# Can I use different passwords for different Netflix profiles?

Tags: account-management, netflix

I bought Netflix and I can set multiple profiles (for different people) under my account. But they would have to sign with my e-mail and password. I don't want to share these credentials with them.

**Is it possible for the others to log to their profile from their own account?**

**Or can I link my profile with another existing Netflix account?**